# Letting the users continue from where they left in embedded PDFs?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, google-drive-api

I have PDFs that I have stored in my google drive and embedded into my site. I wanted the site visitors to be able to continue reading from where they left off when they reload, or when they leave the site and comeback. I tried to get the scrollTop value but that returned zero.

Either the page number or the scroll position would work just fine. Is there anyway to achieve this at all? Because I haven't found anything on the internet about this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the scrolling state. To do you could use url fragments. Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419183/change-url-hash-on-scroll-and-keep-back-button-working/37653797) for more info and code working example